# Reading in Multiple Variables Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a function I'm trying to execute which calls in 4 different variables:

```
def listdbtables(dbname, user, host, password):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" % dbname, % user, % host, % password)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        b = curs.execute("\l")
        print b
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, ex:
        print "I am unable to connect the database: " + ex
        sys.exit(1)
```

I am unable to read in the variables with my current setup, how do I call in the variables properly in the conn variables.

Edit: Here is the error I am seeing:

```
      File "./pg_meta.py", line 35
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" (% dbname, % user, % host, % password))
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
def listdbtables(dbname, user, host, password):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" % (dbname, user, host,password,))
        curs = conn.cursor()
        b = curs.execute("\l")
        print b
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, ex:
        print "I am unable to connect the database: " + ex
        sys.exit(1)
```

the format portion needs to be a tuple for multiple values. you should also consider using [String.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is wrong syntax:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" % dbname, % user, % host, % password)
```

Change it to:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" %(dbname, user, host, password))
```

another way it to use `.format()`:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = {0} username = {1} host = {2} pass = {3}".format(dbname, user, host, password))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is saying that you have incorrect syntax in your program. When using the `%` operator with multiple variables Python requires you to use parenthesis. Change your code to this instead:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = %s username = %s host = %s pass = %s" % (dbname, % user, % host, % password))
```

However, the recommend way to format variables into strings in newer Python versions would be to use the `.format()` method, instead of old style string formatting with `%`:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = {} username = {} host = {} pass = {}".format(
    dbname,  user, host,  password)
)
```

Both methods have their advantageous and disadvantageous, so I encourage you to find which one works best for you. A good website to compare the two methods is [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/).